# RegEx to find specific URL structure

Tags: regex

I have the following URLs

```
http://mysite/us/product.aspx
http://mysite/de/support.aspx
http://mysite/spaces/product-space
http://mysite/spaces/product-space/forums/this is my topic
http://mysite/spaces/product-space/forums/here is another topic
http://mysite/spaces/support-zone
http://mysite/spaces/support-zone/forums/yet another topic
http://mysite/spaces/internal
http://mysite/spaces/internal/forums/final topic
http://mysite/support/product/default.aspx
```

<strike>I want to add a Crawl Rule (This is SharePoint 2010 search related) using RegEx that excludes the URLs that don't include `/forums/*`, leaving only the forum topic URLs.</strike>

I want a rule that excludes the URLs for `../spaces/space1` and `../spaces/space2` but leaves all others intact, including the URLs containing `/forums/`

i.e. here are the results I want to identify with the regex (which will be used in an 'exclude' rule in SharePoint Search):

```
http://mysite/spaces/product-space
http://mysite/spaces/support-zone
http://mysite/spaces/internal
```

leaving these results not matched by the regex (and therefore not excluded by this rule)

```
http://mysite/us/product.aspx
http://mysite/de/support.aspx
http://mysite/spaces/product-space/forums/this is my topic
http://mysite/spaces/product-space/forums/here is another topic
http://mysite/spaces/support-zone/forums/yet another topic
http://mysite/spaces/internal/forums/final topic
http://mysite/support/product/default.aspx
```

Can someone help me out? I've been looking at this all morning and my head is starting to hurt - I can't explain it, I just don't get regular expression structures.

Thanks

Kevin

Comment: I was thinking something along the lines of: 
if URL contains /spaces/ AND there are only 4 forward slashes, then match the expression (and exclude those results). 

Not sure if that makes sense

Comment: Just so I'm sure I understand you correctly, should e.g. `http://mysite/spaces/space1/forums/here is another topic` be excluded or not? (contains `/forums/`)

Comment: Can you show what you want your output to look like (what will be returned)? Given what you're saying, I don't understand if, for example, `http://mysite/spaces/space2/forums/yet another topic` would be included since it matches the exclude AND include conditios you mention...

Comment: Thanks for the patience. I've updated the question again, to show what I want to identify (matched by the regex), and what should be left (i.e. not matched by the regex)

Comment: Will it always be `http://mysite/spaces/space1` / `http://mysite/spaces/space2`? What EXACTLY are you looking to match since we may help you with this particular example, but it's not what you're really looking for....

Comment: Good call: these are examples. Real URLs are `https://www.mysite.com/spaces/product-space` & `https://www.mysite.com/spaces/support-zone` & `https://www.mysite.com/spaces/internal`. In all URLs the domain is the same, as is the folder for `spaces`, but the end of the spaces URL can change. Updated question again, with proper examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lookahead to assert that `/forum/` is in the URL (matches if present):

```
^(?=.*/forums/)
```

Or negative lookahead to assert it's not present:

```
^(?!.*/forums/)
```

**Update:**

This regex will match the url's you have in the "exclude" list:

```
^(?!.*/forums/).*/spaces/(?:space1|space2)
```

In short, we exclude all urls containing `/forums/` using a negative lookahead, then we match anything containing `/spaces/space1` or `/spaces/space2`.

Some systems require you to match the entire line however, in which case you would need to add a `.*` at the end:

```
^(?!.*/forums/).*/spaces/(?:space1|space2).*
```

Comment: Thanks for helping - I realized I'd not given all the requirements, so I've updated the original question.

Comment: OK cool. I'll plug this in (having adapted it back into my real world URLs) and see what happens.

Comment: Unfortuantely John called it. My real world URLs aren't as static as my initial example, so specifying `:space1|space2` isn't going to work, and can't be easily adapted. I, again, updated the original question with better examples.

Comment: @QMKevin, see my updated solution, but, as I stated, please award the answer to rvalvik - He come up with the correct pattern.

Comment: If you want to exclude all urls not containing `/forums/` but containing `/spaces/` then John Bustos' modified pattern will work very well.

I was under the impression you only wanted to exclude certain "spaces" as long as they didn't have `/forums/` in them, in which case yo would add them to the "list". So with your real examples that would be: `^(?!.*/forums/).*/spaces/(?:support-zone|internal|product-space).*`

Answer (score 2):

... In `Multi-line` mode (assuming one URL per line), this did the trick for me:

```
(.*?\/forums\/.*?)$
```

Hope this helps

### **UPDATE:**

Given your comment, the pattern to use could be:

```
.*/spaces/(?!.*/).*
```

Basically saying Match lines that have `/spaces/` but don't have any more `/` after that (as stated was your criteria in your comment).

---

Using @rvalvik's regex suggestion (a different way that is also very nice), your answer would look like:

```
^(?!.*/forums/).*/spaces/.*
```

Comment: Thanks for helping - I realized I'd not given all the requirements, so I've updated the original question.

Comment: Thanks for the help, both of you. I've marked rvalvik's reply as the answer, as requested. I'm having trouble getting this to work in SharePoint, but that's another issue for another stackoverflow site <g> - it works in my regex tester, so I'm happy :)

Comment: ... I updated my answer and gave you another option for the regex - Maybe that one will be better. Either way, glad you got it working (and thanks for the Regex practice :) )